# request.getParameter value not get data with spaces from value that user key in

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, getparameter

I just learn jsp and Java and still new to it.
I have this code in my **a.jsp** file.The user will need to enter any item in the value and click button Search.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="itemCode" id="itemCode">;
<input type="button" name="btnitemsearch" value="Search" onclick="searchItem();">
```

Then in the function searchItem(),

```
var code1 = document.getElementById("itemCode").value;
var getData = '../select_Item/b.jsp?itemCode=' + code1;

$(document).ready (function(){
     $("#openModalDialog").dialog({
         modal: true,
         autoOpen: false,
         title: "Item Search",
         width: 700,
         height: 400,
         });
     });

     $('#openModalDialog').dialog('open');
      $('#openModalDialog').load(getData);
```

So in **b.jsp** file, I use request get parameter to get the value but it only works if the value have no space.

```
<% String itemCode= request.getParameter("itemCode");
   System.out.println(itemCode);%>
```

Example if I enter value pencil of course it does print out "pencil".
But if I enter value pencil 2b if only print out "pencil" without space " " and 2b.

I know that this question have been asked and duplicate.But in most of the question asked, the value use request.getParameter.It says that I need to surround the attribute value with quotes.

```
value="<%=request.getParameter("anything")%>"
```

But in my question is if the value have to be enter by the user.How to make it work ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
var getData = '../select_Item/b.jsp?itemCode=' + code1;
```

by

```
var getData = '../select_Item/b.jsp?itemCode=' + encodeURIComponent(code1);
```

You need to encode your query string to form a correct URL string.

In this case: `pencil 2b` will become `pencil%202b`, and the space character is correctly preserved while accessing in your `b.jsp`